# How do I use ROW_NUMBER in MySQL to check number of rows per day per employee?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm storing punch-in and punch-out data in a table that looks like so:

| id | empid | punchtime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 74 | 4 | 2021-08-04 17:11:54 |
| 171 | 4 | 2021-08-06 13:47:45 |
| 202 | 4 | 2021-08-09 10:14:01 |
| 271 | 4 | 2021-08-09 18:20:01 |
| 308 | 4 | 2021-08-10 11:14:54 |
| 343 | 4 | 2021-08-10 14:46:21 |
| 349 | 4 | 2021-08-10 15:22:10 |
| 380 | 4 | 2021-08-10 18:10:58 |
| 406 | 4 | 2021-08-11 10:13:48 |

I want to check for punch in vs. punch out per day. So each odd n-th punch is considered a punch in, and each even n-th punch is considered a punch out. I also have a table with employee information, i.e. employee ID and name.

Here's my SQL query:

```sql
WITH PunchDataPlus AS (
SELECT pd.*, ei.Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmpID, datediff(PunchTime, '2021-08-11')=0 ORDER BY PunchTime) AS RN 
FROM PunchData pd LEFT JOIN EmployeeInfo ei ON pd.EmpID=ei.EmpID
), FinalPunchData AS (
SELECT PunchDataPlus.*, CASE WHEN RN % 2 =1 THEN 'IN' ELSE 'OUT' END AS inOutCol FROM PunchDataPlus
) 
SELECT * FROM FinalPunchData WHERE EmpID=4 ORDER BY PunchTime DESC;
```

The problem with this query is that the `datediff` can only compare against one day at a time. How do I compare against each day so that each day has its own in/out values?

The result of the SQL query:

| id | EmpID | PunchTime | Name | RN | inOutCol |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 406 | 4 | 2021-08-11 10:13:48 | ***redacted*** | 1 | IN |
| 380 | 4 | 2021-08-10 18:10:58 | ***redacted*** | 8 | OUT |
| 349 | 4 | 2021-08-10 15:22:10 | ***redacted*** | 7 | IN |
| 343 | 4 | 2021-08-10 14:46:21 | ***redacted*** | 6 | OUT |
| 308 | 4 | 2021-08-10 11:14:54 | ***redacted*** | 5 | IN |
| 271 | 4 | 2021-08-09 18:20:01 | ***redacted*** | 4 | OUT |
| 202 | 4 | 2021-08-09 10:14:01 | ***redacted*** | 3 | IN |
| 171 | 4 | 2021-08-06 13:47:45 | ***redacted*** | 2 | OUT |
| 74 | 4 | 2021-08-04 17:11:54 | ***redacted*** | 1 | IN |

The result I'm looking for:

| id | EmpID | PunchTime | Name | RN | inOutCol |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 406 | 4 | 2021-08-11 10:13:48 | ***redacted*** | 1 | IN |
| 380 | 4 | 2021-08-10 18:10:58 | ***redacted*** | 4 | OUT |
| 349 | 4 | 2021-08-10 15:22:10 | ***redacted*** | 3 | IN |
| 343 | 4 | 2021-08-10 14:46:21 | ***redacted*** | 2 | OUT |
| 308 | 4 | 2021-08-10 11:14:54 | ***redacted*** | 1 | IN |
| 271 | 4 | 2021-08-09 18:20:01 | ***redacted*** | 2 | OUT |
| 202 | 4 | 2021-08-09 10:14:01 | ***redacted*** | 1 | IN |
| 171 | 4 | 2021-08-06 13:47:45 | ***redacted*** | 1 | IN |
| 74 | 4 | 2021-08-04 17:11:54 | ***redacted*** | 1 | IN |

Comment: so you always want to assume they are out at midnight (in whatever timezone the punch times are in, which I truly hope is utc)?

Comment: @ysth Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try changing `datediff(PunchTime, '2021-08-11')=0` to `DATE(PunchTime)`. This will extract just the date portion of your datetime value and thus as desired partition your data by each day.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to compare days, you simply need your window to be empid and day:

```
select pd.*,
    case (row_number() over (partition by empid, date(punchtime) order by punchtime)) % 2
        when 1 then 'IN'
        else 'OUT'
    end in_out
from PunchData pd
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=839e306edd162f2e1e12c64345db7443)

But you really truly should not be doing this.  You should store IN/OUT with the punch data; when someone punches in or out, they know what they are intending and that intent should get stored.  Even if for some reason you only get the raw times, you should calculate the IN/OUT and store it when you import the data, so that errors in inferring that intent can be corrected in the data, not persisted.

Other problems with this approach: you don't support clocking in before midnight and out after.  If you are storing the times in UTC (which you should), midnight UTC may be an inappropriate time for you to draw the line where everyone is assumed to be out.  If you are not storing the times in UTC, you have the daylight savings problem where a punch in at 1:45am (using US DST rules as an example) may be followed by a punch out at 1:15am, appearing out of order (as well as making computation of time clocked in ambiguous).

Comment: added some commentary to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Please check this one. Enable where clause when search with specific empid otherwise disable it.

```
-- MySQL(v5.8)
SELECT t.id
     , t.empid
     , t.punchtime
     , ei.name
     , t.row_num RN
     , CASE t.row_num % 2
            WHEN 1 THEN 'IN'
            ELSE 'OUT'
       END inOutCol
FROM (SELECT id
           , empid
           , punchtime
           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY empid, CAST(punchtime AS DATE) ORDER BY punchtime) row_num
      FROM PunchData
      WHERE empid = 4) t
LEFT JOIN EmployeeInfo ei
       ON t.empid = ei.empid
ORDER BY t.punchtime DESC;
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4236c0424e87fe25be6033dcc93b4856

Comment: there's no need for a subquery here.  not sure what the 5.7 comment is for; this won't work in 5.7.

Comment: Hi @ysth try to write this one for more readable and think about performance . Mention version here because you know lower version of mysql doesn't support ROW_NUMBER().

Comment: Hi @AidanHakimian you can add flag column in PunchData table for distinguishing punch in and out. i.e 1 = IN , 2 = OUT

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide an employee table so i removed it from the query.

please add it in your database

> ```
> CREATE TABLE PunchData
>     (`id` int, `empid` int, `punchtime` varchar(19))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO PunchData
>     (`id`, `empid`, `punchtime`)
> VALUES
>     (74, 4, '2021-08-04 17:11:54'),
>     (171, 4, '2021-08-06 13:47:45'),
>     (202, 4, '2021-08-09 10:14:01'),
>     (271, 4, '2021-08-09 18:20:01'),
>     (308, 4, '2021-08-10 11:14:54'),
>     (343, 4, '2021-08-10 14:46:21'),
>     (349, 4, '2021-08-10 15:22:10'),
>     (380, 4, '2021-08-10 18:10:58'),
>     (406, 4, '2021-08-11 10:13:48')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> WITH PunchDataPlus AS (
> SELECT pd.*
> , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmpID, DATE(PunchTime) ORDER BY PunchTime) AS RN 
> FROM PunchData pd 
>
> ), FinalPunchData AS (
> SELECT PunchDataPlus.*, CASE WHEN RN % 2 =1 THEN 'IN' ELSE 'OUT' END AS inOutCol FROM PunchDataPlus
> ) 
> SELECT * FROM FinalPunchData WHERE EmpID=4 ORDER BY PunchTime DESC;
> ```

> ```
>  id | empid | punchtime           | RN | inOutCol
> --: | ----: | :------------------ | -: | :-------
> 406 |     4 | 2021-08-11 10:13:48 |  1 | IN      
> 380 |     4 | 2021-08-10 18:10:58 |  4 | OUT     
> 349 |     4 | 2021-08-10 15:22:10 |  3 | IN      
> 343 |     4 | 2021-08-10 14:46:21 |  2 | OUT     
> 308 |     4 | 2021-08-10 11:14:54 |  1 | IN      
> 271 |     4 | 2021-08-09 18:20:01 |  2 | OUT     
> 202 |     4 | 2021-08-09 10:14:01 |  1 | IN      
> 171 |     4 | 2021-08-06 13:47:45 |  1 | IN      
>  74 |     4 | 2021-08-04 17:11:54 |  1 | IN
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2eb1471c345fcaab1f5d2a7077307861)*